# How to Show 3 Ads in 1 Row via CSS?

Tags: css

I am using Blogger, and in my recent blog I want to show three link ads in one row like below screenshot. I have tried it out with HTML, but I couldn't find a solution. Can I do it with CSS?

[image: Link ads screenshot]

Comment: Yes.  You can do it with CSS.  Look up how "float" works.

Comment: where is the code? try this: `adscontainer { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put them in an inline-block list

```
<ul class="ad-list">
    <li>Ad here</li>
    <li>Ad here</li>
    <li>Ad here</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS would be:

```
ul.ad-list{list-style:none;}
ul.ad-list li{display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;margin-right:#px;}
ul.ad-list li:last-child{margin-right:0;}
```

Hopes this helps to get you on the right track.